# Index Seek estimated rows

Tags: sql-server, cardinality

Question is about MS SQL Server 2008+.

Having table (say,  5-10M rows)

```
CREATE TABLE [Test].[Persons](
[PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
[OtherNames] [varchar] (50) NULL,
[BirthDate] [varchar] (10) NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_Persons] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PersonId] ASC)
)
```

With index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Persons_LastName_FirstName] 
ON [Test].[Persons] ([LastName] ASC, [FirstName] ASC)
```

Executing simple query like

```
SELECT [FirstName],[LastName],[BirthDate] 
FROM [Test].[Persons] WHERE [LastName] = 'Decker'
```

I see, that with **Index Seek** operator, when key is not in statistics histogram exact values, estimated rows differ from actual rows badly.
For some particular keys it can be about 15 estimated rows vs 10k actual rows. 

Seems like in this case “Estimated rows” value is taken directly from AVG_RANGE_ROWS for corresponding interval (i.e. next histogram value).

Is it expected behaviour? I mean, does SQL Server “knows” that value is not exact and uses this fact in computing query cost, or it is a potential wrong query plan problem?

Tried with SQL2008R2, 2012, 2014 (all with OLD Cardinality Estimator) As far as I know, new CE changes things only when dealing with multiple tables in query. It is interesting to try, but I haven’t yet.

Comment: I suppose it is because the statistics sample only guesses at how many DECKER you are likely to have - try some common and rare names and see if there is a pattern

Comment: Try running UPDATE STATISTICS

Comment: @Tab Alleman Statistics were updated WITH FULLSCAN just before the query execution.

Comment: Please provide your execution plan

Comment: It would be also nice to see your histogram with Last names you are trying.

Comment: @SlavaMurygin, Devart, Andrew - thanks for your comments, I did some reading on statistics and some experiments and posted an answer as a result

Answer (score 0):

I did some work on this question and made it clear.

**Short answer**: Well, shame on me. It’s exactly how statistics works. In my case additional filtered statistics would win. Thanks for comments, they were really useful to start checking.

**Long answer**:
The “problem” was in keys distribution over data. I had all 200 steps in histogram filled and it couldn’t gather any more info about exact very common values. Over more than 500k of relatively rare distinct values it gave obvious (for me now) effect.

I've made a simple example script, demonstrating similar behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE [TestStatistics] (
[Id] [INT] IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
[Val] [INT] NOT NULL
)
GO
--Insert 200k rows with ~60k distinct values
insert into TestStatistics (Val) VALUES (CHECKSUM (newid())%30000)
go 200000
--Insert 100k rows with ~600 distinct values, that are multiples of 100
insert into TestStatistics (Val) VALUES (CHECKSUM (newid())%300*100)
GO 100000

create nonclustered index IX_TestStatistics_Val on TestStatistics(Val ASC)
GO
```

So, I have inserted 300k total rows with ~60k distinct values, which means a density of ~0.2 over the table. And I have “special” 100k rows that are filled with ~600 distinct values - multiples of 100. That is, any of this rows is encountered ~166 times. 
And statistics now are looking like this:

[Statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1YLt.png)

Now, if I take any of 100’s multiple, which is absent in histogram (for example, 7500), I will get estimate for 4.5-5.5 rows and nearly 166 actual rows. Estimated value is really just next AVG_RANGE_ROWS value from histogram (for 7500 - at Val=7800).

Now, if I gather some additional stats, like

```
CREATE STATISTICS ST_TestStatistics_0_10000 
ON TestStatistics(Val) WHERE Val>=0 AND Val<10000
```

I will get another query plan:

[Query Plans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9E1i.png)